# Generating monthly payments table for subscription

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following two tables in a database:

**subscriptions**: Each account number can have multiple subscriptions (A,B,C), which each have their own start/end dates and annual fees.

| AccountNumber | Subscription | StartDate | EndDate | AnnualFee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1/1/2022 | 6/5/2022 | 600 |
| 123 | B | 1/1/2022 | 7/5/2022 | 280 |
| 123 | C | 4/2/2022 | 18/8/2022 | 450 |
| 123 | A | 7/5/2022 | 18/8/2022 | 650 |
| 123 | B | 8/5/2022 | 18/8/2022 | 330 |

**calendar**: Consists of all days of the year from 1 Jan to 1 August.

| Date | WeekofYr | MonthStart | MonthEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1 | 1/1/2022 | 31/1/2022 |
| 2/1/2022 | 1 | 1/1/2022 | 31/1/2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 31/7/2022 | 31 | 1/7/2022 | 31/7/2022 |
| 1/8/2022 | 32 | 1/8/2022 | 31/8/2022 |

**monthly_payments (expected output):**
Subscriptions are billed to each account on a monthly basis. The objective I am trying to achieve is to build an output which shows the monthly payment expected, and YTD payments, from 1 Jan to 31 July. I managed to do this in python/pandas using some manual programming logic, but I was wondering if there is a way to produce this output in sql itself? It would be very efficient if possible. I am not too concerned about which SQL RDMBS to use (can be either postgres, mysql or sqlite).

| AccountNumber | MonthStart | MonthEnd | NumDaysinMonth | FeesPaid | YTDPaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1/1/2022 | 31/1/2022 | 31 | **74.74** (Subscription A and B cost 880/year total. 880/365 * 31 = 74.74 dollars that needs to be paid in Jan) | 74.74 |
| 123 | 1/2/2022 | 28/2/2022 | 28 | **98.33** (There is 880/365 * 28 = 67.51 that needs to be paid for subscriptions A and B just like last month. But now there is also subscription C which started on 4/2/2022, which costs 450/365 * 25 = 30.82 for this month. So total expected payment for Feb is 67.51+30.82=98.33 | **173.07** (98.33+74.74) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 123 | 1/7/2022 | 31/7/2022 | 31 | ... | ... |

Comment: Pick one database instead of tagging a bunch of different ones.

Comment: @Shawn updated to mysql

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.0, you can use the window function `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY *expr* ORDER BY *expr*)` to calculate the running total.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac09cc10b005c3138a6211c4bd662783)

```
SELECT
    accountnumber, monthstart, monthend, numdaysinmonth,
    ROUND(feespaid, 2) AS feespaid, 
    ROUND(SUM(feespaid) OVER(PARTITION BY accountnumber ORDER BY monthstart), 2) AS ytdpaid
FROM (
    SELECT 
    accountnumber, monthstart, monthend,
    datediff(monthend, monthstart)+1 AS numdaysinmonth, 
    SUM(annualfee/365) AS feespaid
    FROM subscriptions s
    JOIN calendar c ON c.date BETWEEN s.startdate AND s.enddate
    -- since you mentioned 1 Jan to 31 July
    WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-07-31'     
    GROUP BY accountnumber, monthstart, monthend
    ORDER BY accountnumber, monthstart, monthend
) tmp
;
```